# Get random and no-repeated object from an array

Tags: java, performance, random

I have five colors which saved in an array:

```
int[] colors=new int[]{Color.red,Color.black,Color.blue,Color.gray,Color.green};
```

Now I have a lot of items, and I want give a **random** color for each item with two requirements:

1 Color muse be chosen from the array

2 One item can not have the same color with that next to it.

```
int[] colors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.category_color_array);

ArrayList<Integer> cs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int k = 0; k < items.size(); k++) {
    if (k <= colors.length - 1) {
        cs.add(colors[k]);
    } else {
        cs.add(colors[k - colors.length]);
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(cs);
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    items.get(i).color = cs.get(i);
}
cs.clear();
```

But I always get the repeated colors for two items,how to fix it?

BTW, my application will run on Andriod, so performance should be under consideration.

Comment: What are the sizes of `items()` and `colors`?

Comment: colors have 5 elements while the items are not sure.

Answer (score 1):

you can choose random colors for position i where cs[i] != cs[i - 1]

```
    ArrayList<Integer> cs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // assume we have 15 item 
    for (int k = 0; k < items.size(); k++) {

        int color = gerRandomColor(colors);

        //System.out.println(rand);
        while(k > 0 && color == cs.get(k - 1)){
            color = gerRandomColor(colors);
        }

        cs.add(color);
    }
```